# SharePoint 2013 Word Document Downloading

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, office

I have a user who is complaining that when he clicks on a link within a document library it automatically downloads the file to his PC, rather than letting him open it and edit it.

He is the only user that is experiencing this problem.

I have checked his security level and it is no different than anyone else.

Also, this occurs in multiple browsers for him.

Anyone have any ideas on what I could troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the default behavior for opening documents for entire site, activate a site collection feature "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default". This should force the documents to be opened in client application.

To set the behavior at library level, go to library settings -> Advanced Settings -> and set Opening Document in the Browser to 'Open in Client Application'

For reference on default behavior see [this article on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425%28v=office.15%29.aspx)